# Textmate bundle for AspectJ?

Tags: textmate

Where can I get a [Textmate](http://macromates.com/) bundle for [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I am very confident to say that there is no such thing.

If you don't know it yet, [GetBundles](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/GetBundles.tmbundle/) lists (almost) all available TM Bundles and there is none for AspectJ. Also, Google turns up nothing which I can imagine you already tried searching. The syntax itself should be Java-like so at least syntax coloring will work pretty well I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In TextMate 2, bundles are listed in Preferences:bundles (⌘-,)

I don't see one there for AspectJ (aspect-oriented programming plug-in for Java)

There's a syntax highlighter bundle for sublime text which should port pretty readily. Perhaps do this, and get the TextMate guys to add it to their list once you've got it working.